# ORDER BY num-rows of another table

Tags: mysql, sql

**I have to create a ranking of the directors who have made the most reviews. What is the method for reordering according to the number of rows in another table?**

Table 1 (director)

```
+-------------+--------------+
|    name     |    company   |  
+-------------+--------------+
| John        | John SPA     |
| Mark        | Marks Food   |
| Patrick     | Patrick & CO |
+-------------+--------------+
```

Table 2 (employee_reviews)

```
+-------------+--------------+----------+---------+
|   director  |    employee  |   Text   |  Stars  |
+-------------+--------------+----------+---------+
| John        | Omar         | ...      | 3       |
| John        | Richard      | ...      | 5       |
| Mark        | Simon        | ...      | 5       |
| Patrick     | David        | ...      | 1       |
| Patrick     | Omar         | ...      | 2       |
| John        | Simon        | ...      | 4       |
+-------------+--------------+----------+---------+
```

---

**Result (Directors ranking):**

```
1st) Dir. John [3 reviews]
2nd) Dir. Patrick [2 reviews]
3rd) Dir. Mark [1 review]
...
```

Comment: Show us your code, please.

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: What does PHP have to do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join to your table and select the count when (ON) the author equals the director, then you group the rows by the director results, and then you order it.

Example: `SELECT *, COUNT(reviews.id) FROM directors JOIN reviews ON reviews.author = directors.director GROUP BY direcotrs.director ORDER BY COUNT(reviews.id) DESC;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the tables first, on director.name=employee_reviews.director. Then you can do `select name, count(*) ... group by name`.

Comment: Right, I overlooked that you wanted that too. The `row_number` window function can do this, or if you're more comfortable with it, you can do it in your application code. If you add an `order by`, you'll get the rows in that order.

Answer (score 0):

Just alias the count column and order descendingly by it within the grouped query by director for `table2` :

```
 SELECT Director, Count(*) as count
   FROM Table2
  GROUP BY Director
  ORDER BY count DESC
```

there's nothing to do with `Table1` unless some other extra columns of it(such as company) needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't actually need the count you can use a subquery in the `order by`:

```
select d.*
from directors d
order by (select count(*) 
          from employee_reviews er
          where er.director = d.nme
         ) desc;
```

I would be very careful about this question and about directors who have no reviews.  If you want the number of reviews in the result set (which would be an extension of the question you asked), then one method is to move the correlated subquery to the `select`:

```
select d.*,
       (select count(*) 
        from employee_reviews er
        where er.director = d.nme
       ) as num_reviews
from directors d
order by num_reviews desc;
```

Or use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select d.*
from directors d left join
     employee_reviews er
     on er.director = d.name
group by d.name  -- allowed if this is declared unique or a primary key
order by count(er.director) desc;
```